# header in WP Child Theme not loading consistently

Tags: css, wordpress, header

For this site: http://kayleerosemusic.com/ I'm using this theme: https://organicthemes.com/demo/music/ -- I have customized it and made a child theme. My functions.php is:

```
<?php

/**
 * Organic Music child theme.
 */

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'music_child_enqueue_styles' );
function music_child_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'music-theme-parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
```

I have added two custom headers which randomly load. This is supported by the theme. In the parent theme, the headers load fine on the home page every time. In the child theme they do not. Sometimes they load, sometimes not and it's worse on mobile devices.

I have tried stripping out ALL the customizations and having just a blank style.css file in the child theme and I still have the issue. I can't figure out what might be causing this to happen in the child theme and not the parent theme.

My style.css in the child theme is:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/*
 Theme Name: Kaylee Rose
 Theme URI: /wp-content/themes/kaylee-rose/
 Description: Organic Music Child Theme
 Author: Design Intense
 Author URI: http://designintense.com
 Text Domain: kaylee-rose
 Template: organic-music
 Version: 1.0.1
*/
```

Any light that can be shed on this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified your code (path and filename) as per - https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes. You should call  `wp_enqueue_style()` method twice - once for the parent theme and also once for the child theme (with the parent as a dependency)

Comment: turns out it was something in the database left over from the original site. when the header didn't load fast enough it would look for this other file and when that wasn't found, it showed a blank square. so i just mocked it up by saving one of the headers with the filename and path it was looking for and that did the trick.